# Python. How to Subsample points (X,Y)

Tags: python

I have a list with 10,000 points [x,y], but they are very near each other so I would like to subsample this list with a given distance threshold.
I'm not sure which is the best way or the right manner to do it.

**This is my pseudo code**

```
coordinates = [x,y]
thresholdDist = 'some float value'
subsample = []
points = 'pick-some-random-points-from-coordinates'
for p in points:
    for c in coordinates:
        dst=EuclideanDistance(p, c)
            if dst <= thresholdDist:
                subsample.append(p and c)
set(subsample)
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: This actually looks correct except for 1) `p and c` (not what you'd want) and, 2) Could be more pythonic..

Comment: The next step is to convert your pseudo-code into real code.

Comment: @Thrustmaster I haven't a formal education into programming  so I realliy don't know what does a code is more pytonic